# add legend for vertical bar chart in vue chart js

Tags: vue.js, charts, vue-chartjs

I am using chart js `^2.9.4` and vue chart js `^3.5.1` to draw a vertical bar chart. There my intention is to add a legend for representing each bar color. My attempt is as below.

```html
<bar-chart :data="barChartData" :options="barChartOptions" :height="200" />
```

```js
 barChartData: {
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: ['risky', 'go', 'wait'],
        backgroundColor: ["red", "green", "yellow"],
        data: [10, 15, 20]
      }
    ]
},
barChartOptions: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: true,
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Monthly Income'
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

But it will show only one key. How can I show three keys to represent 'risky', 'go' and 'wait' from 'red', 'green' and 'yellow' respectively using legend.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`barChartOptions.legend.labels.generateLabels()`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration) to generate the legend labels per item.

As of Chart.js 2.9.4, the `generateLabels()` method should return an array of [legend items](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/configuration/legend.html#legend-item-interface), each including a `text` property for the label and `fillStyle` for the color of the legend box.

For example, you could map the data labels and background colors into the legend items:

```js
const barLabels = ['risky', 'go', 'wait']
const barBackgroundColors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow']

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      barChartData: {
        labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: barLabels,
            backgroundColor: barBackgroundColors,
            data: [10, 15, 20]
          }
        ]
      },
      barChartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
          display: true,
          labels: {
            generateLabels() {
              return barLabels.map((label, index) => ({
                text: label,
                fillStyle: barBackgroundColors[index]
              }))
            }
          }
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-chartjs-bar-chart-with-legend?file=src/App.vue)